# Angular 2 Testing a component with an observable without mocking

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, integration-testing, observable

I have been trying to create integration tests using Jasmine for an Angular 2 project. I can mock services and data just fine and run the appropriate unit tests, but now I want to test to make sure that my component can use the service to actually connect to the back end API. So far, I can confirm that my methods inside both my component and service are being triggered from my spy's, but the .subscribe(....) method within my component will not complete until after the test is finished/failed. My code for my spec is as follows:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed, inject, fakeAsync } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { DebugElement } from "@angular/core";
import { By } from "@angular/platform-browser";

import { ReviewComponent } from './review.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { UrlService } from 'app/shared/services/url.service';
import { HttpModule, Http } from '@angular/http';
import { ReviewService } from "./review.service";

describe('CommunicationLogComponent', () => {
  let component: ReviewComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ReviewComponent>;
  let serviceSpy: jasmine.Spy;
  let componentSpy: jasmine.Spy;
  let service: ReviewService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [FormsModule, HttpModule],
      providers: [UrlService],
      declarations: [ReviewComponent]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ReviewComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.processId = 6;
    service = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(ReviewService);
    componentSpy = spyOn(component, "ngOnInit").and.callThrough();
    serviceSpy = spyOn(service, 'getReviewByProcess').and.callThrough();
  });

  it('should create component', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
  it('should not have called ngOnInit() yet', () => {
    expect(componentSpy).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

  it('should make a call to ngOnInit() and by extension getReviewByProcess', () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(componentSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(serviceSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
  //ISSUES HERE
  it('should show review after the getReviewByProcess resolves', async(() => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      expect(componentSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
      fixture.detectChanges();
      expect(component.Reviews[0]).not.toBe(undefined);
    });
  }), 5000);        
});
```

All tests up until the one marked with "//ISSUES HERE" are working fine and pass.

I am using async() and waiting for the fixture to become stable before attempting to finish out my test. It also confirms via the componentSpy that ngOnInit has been called (Which will connect to the backend and subscribe to a Review).

My component code looks like this:

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

//Service 
import { ReviewService } from "app/process/monitoring/shared/components/review/review.service";

//Classes
import { Review } from "app/process/monitoring/shared/components/review/review";

@Component({
  providers: [
    ReviewService
  ],
  selector: 'monitoring-review',
  templateUrl: './review.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./review.component.css']
})
export class ReviewComponent implements OnInit {

  public Review: Review = new Review();
  public Reviews: Review[] = [];

  @Input() public processId: number;

  constructor(
    private ReviewService: ReviewService
  ) { }


  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.ReviewService.getReviewByProcess(this.processId, true).first().subscribe(
      Reviews => {
        if (Reviews) {
          this.Reviews = Reviews //doesn't trigger until test is finished
        }
      },
      error => console.log(error)
    );
  }
}
```

And finally my ReviewService looks like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Headers, RequestOptions, RequestMethod, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

// App-wide Services
import { UrlService } from 'app/shared/services/url.service';

// Classes
import { Review } from "app/process/monitoring/shared/components/review/review";


@Injectable()
export class ReviewService {

  private devUrl: string;
  private jsonHeaders: Headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
  private prodUrl: string;
  private reviewPath: string = 'monitoring/program/';

  constructor(
    private urlService: UrlService,
    private http: Http
  ) {
    this.devUrl = this.urlService.getUrl('dev').url;
    this.prodUrl = this.urlService.getUrl('prod').url;
  }

  getReviewByProcess(processId: number, isProd: boolean = false): Observable<Review[]> {
    let targetUrl: string = (isProd ? this.prodUrl : this.devUrl) + this.reviewPath + "/" + processId;

    return this.http.get(targetUrl, { withCredentials: true })
      .map((res: Response) => res.json())
      .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error')
      );
  };
}
```

Using the Karma debugger, I can confirm that my test calls the ngOnInit, which then calls to the service, but it never hits the inner part of my components subscribe (marked with the "//doesn't trigger") until after my test is completed.

To summarize: I want to create a test that can test my component integrating with my service using a "live" backend to collect my data. That is the service and my component will not be mocking anything. I can confirm that my methods are being reached but the .subscribe(...) found in my ReviewComponent's ngOnInit() method does not finish until after the test is completed/failed.

Answer (score 2):

You need to return the observable and subscribe to it within the test for the async method to wait for it. For instance the following hypothetical test would work.

```
it('', async(() => {
  observable().subscribe(
    (review) => {
       expect(component.Reviews[0]).not.toBe(undefined)
    }
  )
}));
```

The problem is that you are not waiting for an asynchronous call to execute with in the test. You could alternatively slightly alter the angular http service i.e:

```
import { Http, HttpModule, BaseRequestOptions, XHRBackend, HttpModule, ConnectionBackend } from '@angular/http';
const httpSubject = new Subject()
const http$ = httpSubject.asObservable()
const httpFactory = (backend, options) => {
  const newHttp = new Http(backend, options);
  const helperHttp = new Http(backend, options);
  newHttp.get = function(strng, options) {
    return helperHttp.get(strng, options).do((response) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        httpSubject.next({});
      }, 300);
    });
  };
  return newHttp;
}

TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [HttpModule, FormModule],
  providers: [
    UrlService,
    ConnectionBackend,
    BaseRequestOptions
    {
      provide: Http,
      useFactory: httpFactory,
      deps: [ XHRBackend, BaseRequestOptions] 
    }
  ],
  declarations: [ReviewComponent]
})

it('should show review after the getReviewByProcess resolves', 
  async(() => {
    http$.subscribe(() => {
      expect(componentSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
      expect(component.Reviews[0]).not.toBe(undefined);
    })
    fixture.detectChanges();
}));
```

Comment: The code you have set as an example gave a call stack error even after i placed the appropriate urls, options, etc.

Comment: @LandSharks Sorry, I have updated it and it is working for me locally. Give it a go and if you still have an issue i can send you the test version that i created.

Comment: @LandSharks please comment if you manage to try it out or if you find another solution. It would be good to know.

Answer (score 0):

You need your service to return mock data. Something like that:

```
spyOn(service, 'getReviewByProcess')
   .and.returnValue(Observable.of(new Array<Review>()));
```

Comment: I don't want to return mock data but legitimate data from my web API. Is this just something jasmine cannot support and I should look for solutions using protractor?

Comment: This is unit testing and it should be scoped and dedicated to specific component/function and you need to mock enviroment to archive it. If you want to mock http you can use MockBackend to mock on http service level. If you need to call you Web API for test - use Protractor for end-to-end testing but with great features of angular 2 unit testing I do not see no much need for e2e.

Comment: Does Jasmine not support integration testing then? I noticed on the main doc sight for angular 2: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html#!#component-with-async-service

That they are doing the exact thing I want to, but lacking an http connection. There data was static in their object.

Comment: You can do anything, e.g. you can also test if an HTML input element has a 'required' validator attribute :D